# PHP login system: Remember Me (persistent cookie)

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, remember-me

I'd like to add a "remember me" checkbox option before logging in.

What is the best way to securely store a cookie in the user's browser?

For example, Facebook have their "remember me" checkbox so that every time you enter facebook.com you are already logged in.

My current login uses simple sessions.

Comment: You may take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth and its source to see how to implement a *secure* "remember me" feature. Basically, just store some *very long* (i.e. much entropy) string of random data in a cookie. When the user visits your page, check that "token" against your database where you track these tokens. If the token is valid, authenticate the user.

Answer (score 68):

> **Update (2017-08-13)**: To understand why we're separating `selector` and `token`, instead of just using a `token`, please read [this article about splitting tokens to prevent timing attacks](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/02/split-tokens-token-based-authentication-protocols-without-side-channels) on SELECT queries.

I'm going to extract the strategy outlined in this blog post [about secure long-term authentication](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence) since that covers a lot of ground and we're only interested in the ["remember me"](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2) part.

## Preamble - Database Structure

We want a separate table from our users' table that looks like this (MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE `auth_tokens` (
    `id` integer(11) not null UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `selector` char(12),
    `token` char(64),
    `userid` integer(11) not null UNSIGNED,
    `expires` datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

The important things here are that `selector` and `token` are separate fields.

## After Logging In

If you don't have `random_bytes()`, just grab a copy of [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat).

```
if ($login->success && $login->rememberMe) { // However you implement it
    $selector = base64_encode(random_bytes(9));
    $authenticator = random_bytes(33);

    setcookie(
        'remember',
         $selector.':'.base64_encode($authenticator),
         time() + 864000,
         '/',
         'yourdomain.com',
         true, // TLS-only
         true  // http-only
    );

    $database->exec(
        "INSERT INTO auth_tokens (selector, token, userid, expires) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", 
        [
            $selector,
            hash('sha256', $authenticator),
            $login->userId,
            date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', time() + 864000)
        ]
    );
}
```

## Re-Authenticating On Page Load

```
if (empty($_SESSION['userid']) && !empty($_COOKIE['remember'])) {
    list($selector, $authenticator) = explode(':', $_COOKIE['remember']);

    $row = $database->selectRow(
        "SELECT * FROM auth_tokens WHERE selector = ?",
        [
            $selector
        ]
    );

    if (hash_equals($row['token'], hash('sha256', base64_decode($authenticator)))) {
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['userid'];
        // Then regenerate login token as above
    }
}
```

## Details

We use 9 bytes of random data (base64 encoded to 12 characters) for our selector. This provides 72 bits of keyspace and therefore 2<sup>36</sup> bits of collision resistance (birthday attacks), which is larger than our storage capacity (`integer(11) UNSIGNED`) by a factor of 16.

We use 33 bytes (264 bits) of randomness for our actual authenticator. This should be unpredictable in all practical scenarios.

We store an SHA256 hash of the authenticator in the database. This mitigates the risk of user impersonation following information leaks.

We re-calculate the SHA256 hash of the authenticator value stored in the user's cookie then compare it with the stored SHA256 hash using [`hash_equals()`](https://php.net/hash_equals) to prevent timing attacks.

We separated the selector from the authenticator because DB lookups are not constant-time. This eliminates the potential impact of timing leaks on searches without causing a drastic performance hit.

Comment: Excellent work. Is it worth adding the expiry check in your code? Do you regenerate the token elsewhere in your code (e.g. 1 in 10 page loads)?

Comment: Argh! This looks great and all, but I cannot get `hash_equals` to return true using any of these custom functions: https://php.net/hash_equals#115664

Comment: If you need an in-PHP implementation: https://github.com/sarciszewski/php-future

Comment: You regenerate the token after it's used once.

Comment: What if the user checked remember me and leaves their session open for the duration? Do you regenerate it at any point in the same session?

Comment: No, the remember me is to re-authenticate them when their session expires (i.e. when you turn your computer back on tomorrow). Short-term session authentication should just be a session identifier (i.e. use what PHP gives you).

Comment: @ScottArciszewski is your method safe? I create a clone of the cookie generated by Chrome and put it in Firefox and the user have logged in as chrome. So is it safe?

Comment: @AgainMe Safe against any reasonable threat model. If someone can intercept/clone cookies (malware), there's nothing the server can or should do about that risk. See also: https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem

Comment: Why `selector` and `token`?.  Is token is not enough

Comment: @NaveenDA There is a dedicated article that addresses this: https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/02/split-tokens-token-based-authentication-protocols-without-side-channels

Comment: Thanks @Scott Arciszewski now i got it

Comment: the last if statement in "Re-Authenticating On Page Load" doesn't work for me, can anyone help?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: What does this line mean: // Then regenerate login token as above. Do I have to create selector and authenticator again?

Comment: Yes, they should only be used once.

Comment: You should not query database every time you get a cookie.You should verify the cookie is "signed" by you. Otherwise you can easily get flooded.

Comment: That's a non-concern, to be honest. The only time this "flooding" happens is when people are using ultra-cheap shared hosting instead of running their own infrastructure. But if you "must" do this, be sure to use [PASETO](https://paseto.io) instead of, say, JWT.

Comment: I used this function, it works on hostgator.  and I know its not a strong as the others.. but its good for my small purposes
    $selector = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(9));
    $authenticator = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(33);

Comment: @hamish Why doesn't HostGator let you upgrade to PHP 7? Surely they'll upgrade your PHP version if you open a support ticket? If not, install [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) and pretend you're on PHP 7.

Comment: I like this approach. The only thing I did differently was, rather than relying solely on $_SESSION['userid'], I also set a $_SESSION['selector'] to check against auth_tokens. This way I'm able to invalidate any active sessions (e.g. in the case of a password reset) without having to wait for the PHP session to expire.

Comment: Great solution, thank you! One addition I made to the Re-Authenticating On Page Load section was where I regenerate the login token, I delete the old one from the database. Otherwise my database was quickly flooded during testing!

Comment: I can see that $selector generated by random_bytes(9). Shouldn't it be unique? Consider two different users have same $selector, so what will be happened!?