# Can i use checkboxes to give value to my variables?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I am trying to make something like facebook "keep me logged in".I want to use checkbox for storing data, or just to make a code that will check if the checkbox is clicked, and if yes, it should make `$remember_me: "true";` and if not `$remember_me: "false"`.
**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" /> Keep me logged in
```

Comment: Like all other `<input>` elements, checkboxes have a `value` attribute you can set.

Comment: @ Rakesh Shetty I never done something like this, so i have no idea how to check if checkbox is clicked, i tried on google but haven't got any ideas so far.I keep searching.

Comment: name="remember_me" and check it on its $_POST ?, if its not set it will be empty, if it is set it will be whatever value is.

Comment: @Crion see http://www.downwithdesign.com/web-development-tutorials/adding-remember-feature-php-login-script/. Like this there are many tutorial available. Just ask [Google](https://www.google.com)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Sessions Login with remember me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091951/php-sessions-login-with-remember-me)

Comment: @ Rakesh Shetty why duplicate, i don't want "php sesion login" i just want to try to store value to $remember_me

Comment: so @Crion why just get the post value of that checkbox into the variable? where is the problem ???

Comment: @ Rakesh Shetty Give me few seconds, i will try to make code.

Comment: @Crion for your better understanding see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893927/send-checkbox-value-in-php-form

Comment: @ Rakesh Shetty thank  for ur help, and tutorials u gave me, i made what i wanted and it works perfectly.Thanks once again :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" value="Yes" />

<?php
if (isset($_POST['remember_me'])) {
    $remember_me: "true";
}
else {
    $remember_me: "false"
}
```

I'd probably recommend not stringing the boolean for true/false