# How to maintain session in php until I click logout button?

Tags: php, session

How to achieve to keep alive the session for long time.

**Example:** 
If I logged into a page and after sometime(say 5hrs) the session is getting closed automatically. How to make it alive until I press logout button.

Comment: You need to set a cookie in order to save the session: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091951/php-sessions-login-with-remember-me

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', <seconds>);
```

in your php script that uses sessions

alternatively increase that value within your php.ini when you are server admin. But note that this is server wide.

To make it project / directory local you can also create a .htaccess file for your project containing:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime <seconds>
```

but this may be restricted by the AllowOverride setting of the server

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is using cookies (with a disclaimer on the website!).
Try something like that, where `time()+60*60*24*100` represents the validity of the cookie in seconds.

**IMPORTANT:** in order to let this work with the most recent chrome updates, don't forget the last `NULL` parameter!

```
setcookie("your_cookie_name", $session, time()+60*60*24*100,'/', NULL);
```

Then, in order to use the cookie, just read it and save it in a new session:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['your_parameter_name']) $_SESSION['your_parameter_name'] = $_COOKIE['your_cookie_name'];
```