# Which field type for store cookie in table?

Tags: php, mysql

I want implement remember me feature for my website, for doing this I want use the code of Gustonez: [PHP Sessions Login with remember me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091951/php-sessions-login-with-remember-me)

but I have no idea of the field type of the table for the cookie `($cookiehash)`, a varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need use `varchar` because hash must contain alphanumeric characters. If you are using `md5` or `sha1` to generate hash then you can apply specific length to your hash field.

You can count lenght of your generated hash via `strlen` php function.

Example:

```
echo strlen('hash');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can store any variable type in Cookies, you can not specify the Datatype in PHP. you can just assign the values in cookies or sessions.

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "Suthagar";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> but I have no idea of the field type of the table for the cookie

Why you need to store cookie in database? that's a clear wrong approach. Cookies are stored on client machine (under browser sandbox) and so does that *Remember Me* feature. Thus when next time end user want to login he don't have to fill out the login form again. There is no point in storing the cookie value in database.

Clarify, if this not what you are talking about.

Comment: The cookie are stored in client machine yep, but why the user on other question have stored the copy of the cookie in the database?

Comment: @AgainMe, that's real weird and have never seen someone do that and even I won't do that as well. Do remember, though there is difference b/w cookie and session and session can be stored in DB since session is server side process.

Comment: but you need to compare the cookie stored in client machine with your server, so where this cookie should be saved?

Comment: @AgainMe, looks like you are running on a misconception. for comparing your client cookie need not be stored in DB. you can very well read the client cookie since it's stored by you or your program.

Comment: I understand your opinion about it, but I saw many implementation of this and most save the cookie in the db, and if the session of the user isn't setted the app perform a query that check if the cookie is found on the db and compare it with the client. For example: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128985/php-login-system-remember-me-persistent-cookie

I don't know if you could find this secure or not, seems that you have more experience than me about this topic, so I'll glad to hear your opionion, thanks.

Comment: @AgainMe, Ok, got it but again if you go through the answers, yes they are storing the info in  (that is user-id/token/expire time) DB and not the cookie actually. Also, they preffer to store in Db rather in client cookie because of security reason since cookie hi-jacking can happen. In that case yes please go ahead store the info in DB directly. But still there is no point in storing the cookie itself ... that statement in question created the confusion.

Comment: sorry my bad, I understood wrong, I though that in the db was stored the cookie but instead is the token, sorry and thanks for the time