# Session is no longer than an hour valid

Tags: php, session, ini-set

I have an issue on SESSION. I need a session of 12 hours, so that I have to login in the morning and can access my website whole day long.

I did the following in .htaccess

```
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 43200
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 43200
php_value session.cache_expire 43200
```

In my index.php i have inserted the code below:

```
echo ini_get("session.cookie_lifetime").'<br />';
echo ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime").'<br />';
echo ini_get("session.cache_expire").'<br />';
```

The resuilt I got:

```
43200
43200
43200
```

However if I don't do anything on my website of an hour, the session will be destoryed.

Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: Have you used chrome tools to inspect the cookie's expiration?

Comment: When using Debian, google for "debian php gc session" - Debian PHP session cleaning works a bit different, by using a cronjob. Personally, I encourage everyone to switch to memcached session handler.

Comment: I know this is not what you asked, however, it would be 'better' to store the login details in in a cookie and 'auto login' using the details in the cookie. i.e. set the session login details via the 'auto login' cookie details. Details here: [3128985/php-loginsystem-remember-me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128985/php-loginsystem-remember-me). Some hosting site prohibit long session times.

Comment: @RyanVincent Don't :-( Don't store credentials (no matter if encrypted or not) in Cookies. Leave them in the Session, which is getting stored on the server.

Comment: @DanFromGermany, Sorry, i should have made it clear to not store direct 'login credentials' in the cookie. Instead, generate a 'unique random reference' and store the cureent user login details in the database with the 'reference' as a key. The 'reference' is what is stored in the cookie. It is changed on every 'auto login'. Also, certain user edit functions are not allowed when access is via 'auto login'.

Comment: @RyanVincent I just ment to add a useful extra notice to your helpful comments, it's all fine, you're welcome :-)

Comment: @used2could No I didn't try it. Can you give some more info on that case, as I'm not sure if I understood you well.

Comment: @RyanVincent That's exactly what I'm planning to do if I wont get it up and running using existing functionality. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',12*60*60);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',12*60*60);
ini_set('session.cache_expire',12*60*60);
session_start();
```

Remember to set the environment parameters BEFORE you start any sessions.
Also be careful, NEVER set the value over 65535, which is a bit more than 18 hours!

Comment: Should I do it also in PHP if the following returns 43200: ini_get("session.cookie_lifetime");? In my opinion that wont change anything if I do it once more using PHP. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: you can be sure this way that your script will use the correct settings.